# Custom Endpoints not working

Tags: rest-api

First time creating custom endpoints. Ill be fetching posts from this site from another wordpres install.

Here is my plugin code.

```
/**
* Add endpoint URLs
*/    
public function __construct(){

    add_action('rest_api_init', function(){

        // Get submissions from the database
        register_rest_route('knpv-get','get-submissions', array(
            'methods'=>'GET', 
            'callback' => 'get_submissions_by_email'
            )
        );

    });

}

/**
* Get submisions by email endpoint callback
*/
public function get_submissions_by_email($data){

    $posts = get_posts();
    return $posts;

}
```

But all I get when i view the url (domain/wp-json/knpv-get/) in browser is:

```
    {"namespace":"knpv-get","routes":{"\/knpv-get":{"namespace":"knpv-get","methods":["GET"],"endpoints":[{"methods":["GET"],"args":{"namespace":{"required":false,"default":"knpv-get"},"context":{"required":false,"default":"view"}}}],"_links":{"self":"http:\/\/knoppysdev.com\/vendor-portal\/wp-json\/knpv-get"}},"\/knpv-get\/get-submissions":{"namespace":"knpv-get","methods":["GET"],"endpoints":[{"methods":["GET"],"args":[]}],"_links":{"self":"http:\/\/knoppysdev.com\/vendor-portal\/wp-json\/knpv-get\/get-submissions"}}},"_links":{"up":[{"href":"http:\/\/knoppysdev.com\/vendor-portal\/wp-json\/"}]}}
```

What am I missing, shouldn't it return some posts. Its a fresh install so there's only Hello World to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong route. The first two arguments of `register_rest_route()` ar the namespace, and the route. The URL to a REST API endpoint is:

```
(your domain) + '/wp-json/' + (namespace) + '/' + (route)
```

So the full URL to your endpoint is:

```
http://domain.com/wp-json/knpv-get/get-submissions
```

But you're attempting to view:

```
http://domain.com/wp-json/knpv-get
```

Which won't return the response from your callback function. However if you look closely at the result, you'll see that it's giving you a list of routes under the `knpv-get` namespace:

```
{
  "namespace": "knpv-get",
  "routes": {
    "\/knpv-get": {
      "namespace": "knpv-get",
      "methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "endpoints": [
        {
          "methods": [
            "GET"
          ],
          "args": {
            "namespace": {
              "required": false,
              "default": "knpv-get"
            },
            "context": {
              "required": false,
              "default": "view"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "_links": {
        "self": "http:\/\/knoppysdev.com\/vendor-portal\/wp-json\/knpv-get"
      }
    },
    "\/knpv-get\/get-submissions": {
      "namespace": "knpv-get",
      "methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
      "endpoints": [
        {
          "methods": [
            "GET"
          ],
          "args": [

          ]
        }
      ],
      "_links": {
        "self": "http:\/\/knoppysdev.com\/vendor-portal\/wp-json\/knpv-get\/get-submissions"
      }
    }
  },
  "_links": {
    "up": [
      {
        "href": "http:\/\/knoppysdev.com\/vendor-portal\/wp-json\/"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the above, Ive used that URL and am returned with {"code":"rest_invalid_handler","message":"The handler for the route is invalid","data":{"status":500}}

Comment: Ive used this as the answer because it does solve the issue in the question. Also worth noting that the 'callback' method had to be 'callback' => array($this, 'get_submissions_by_email') to work.